# Can you pass a string variable as a type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Say I had some map with key: string pairs.

```
Const typeMap = {
  a: 'ComplexTypeOne',
  b: 'ComplexTypeTwo'
}
```

I have two different complex types that represent the structure of data returned from two different api endpoints.

```
interface ComplexTypeOne {
  data: {
    dog: bark,
    cat: meow
  }
}

interface ComplexTypeTwo {
    items: [
   'dogs', 'cats', 'gerbils'
}
```

If I wanted to make a generic function that could take in the desired api endpoint and spit out that endpoint's result dynamically, how would I reference what type I expect based on which input I get?

Ideally, I would like to be able to pass a string in dynamically as a type into the function like so.

```
function test(type: 'a' | 'b') {
  const resp: ComplexType<typeMap[type]> = await someAsyncFunc().result; 
  return resp.dog // Be able to infer in intellisense what type resp is by function parameter
}
```

OR is all of this overengineering and should I make a function for each of the 6+ endpoints and make a switch on type to execute whichever I need?

Comment: So... [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpp6gm)? There are various syntax errors in your original post, though, so it's hard to answer with certainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create another map, but this one's at the type-level:

```
type TypeMap = {
    ComplexTypeOne: ComplexTypeOne;
    ComplexTypeTwo: ComplexTypeTwo;
};
```

Also, we'll need the type of your original map to be more specific, using a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const typeMap = {
  a: 'ComplexTypeOne',
  b: 'ComplexTypeTwo'
} as const; // force to be inferred literally
```

Then we just need to add in a generic parameter for your function:

```
async function test<Type extends keyof typeof typeMap>(type: Type): Promise<TypeMap[typeof typeMap[Type]]> {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgWQIaJgXhgbwFgAoGGdALhgHIBhEAW0QBtkAPAFSWQHkxkqANMVIAjSrQbM2nFOwDuIKsQC+ZCDFCQoAbhgB6PTABmIAE7BkcEDBGWAlmCPJTp5ABMYTO1GfomTeGJiBx9TI3QLGDpGFg4uXktCEhg3dCgKfGFSFJAAc0oAIhF0UwBrAqFk0mA0wvpkEDkKrOUVIKIQ53DI6Kk42QVMqphvZHoISgBtLOo3PIhBahqoBYFqXOcROyYFmYBdNqJiBBQYGTRMHCHsqMlY84TKXvv4vm0Z25jpLnkQJ7vvgMQO8iMoQcR0BB4GBgMYAK4wqB2cBwZDQAA85xgbB8YDc6lKyHgICMcC4JLJKAwiAAfAAKE7ISjnACUlAACqYGHYIMhMVxqZNGRTGYLzns9jTrtkDDB6GZLPR0Lk7LCABbOZAfVxQOGmMAwMBw-wAQkOQA)